# c# linq conditional union

Tags: c#, .net, linq

hi I have the following code and would like to only make each union if a condition is true.
I Know I could write a select of if else but wanted to know if there is a slicker Linq way!?

```
        //join the list into one and sort by seqnumber
      SegmentList = Alist.Cast<BaseSegment>()
     .Union(BList.Cast<BaseSegment>()).Union(CList.Cast<BaseSegment>())
     .OrderBy(item => item.SegSeqNumber).ToList();
```

So given the above if ATest =true how do I only iclude Alist like wise if BTest && CTest are true how do I include only BList and Clist

Thanks

Comment: What tests are you talking about? Your code shows nothing.

Comment: My code currently joins the three lits together (Alist BList and CList. I have added three Checkboxes to the form Check box A for including AList etc So I want to update the Segment list to only include the seleced lists base on the checkbox selections...thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it in a LINQ style way with your checkboxes, something like:

```
SegmentList = Alist.Where(i => checkbox1.IsChecked).Cast<BaseSegment>()
.Union(BList.Where(i => checkbox2.IsChecked).Cast<BaseSegment>())
.Union(CList.Where(i => checkbox3.IsChecked).Cast<BaseSegment>())
.OrderBy(item => item.SegSeqNumber).ToList();
```

would work. But I don't think it is either very understandable or efficient.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL for the answers I think they all work but have selected Alex's

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SegmentList = Alist.Cast<BaseSegment>()
                   .Union(includeB ? BList.Cast<BaseSegment>() : Enumerable.Empty<BaseSegment>())
                   .Union(includeC ? CList.Cast<BaseSegment>() : Enumerable.Empty<BaseSegment>())
                   .OrderBy(item => item.SegSeqNumber)
                   .ToList();
```

This is not *identical* to your original (it will remove duplicates from Alist no matter what) but should be what you want.

For any more than 2 conditional unions, you would probably want a different query, something like:

```
var listsByCb = new Dictionary<CheckBox, MyListType>
                {{ aListBox, aList}, {bListBox, bList}, {cListBox, cList}};

var segmentList = listsByCb.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Checked)
                           .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Cast<BaseSegment>())
                           .Distinct();
                           .OrderBy(item => item.SegSeqNumber)
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: +1: appears to have better performance characteristics than mine and others (at maximum only a single check is run for each union), also nice `SelectMany` example.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
SegmentList = Alist.Cast<BaseSegment>().Where(z=>ATest)
     .Union(BList.Cast<BaseSegment>().Where(x=>Btest)).Union(CList.Cast<BaseSegment>().Where(c=>Ctest))
     .OrderBy(item => item.SegSeqNumber).ToList();
```

where class in each case will return all elements if corresponding test is true and will return no element otherwise. its completely untested though

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Where()` clause for that, like following:

```
    //join the list into one and sort by seqnumber
  SegmentList = 
     Alist.Cast<BaseSegment>().Where(a => ATest(a))
     .Union(
        BList.Cast<BaseSegment>(.Where(b => BTest(b))
     .Union(CList.Cast<BaseSegment>().Where(c => CTest(c))
     .OrderBy(item => item.SegSeqNumber).ToList();
```

By the way, do you really need the last `ToList()`?